# iOS - Add Swift pod to Objective-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa, cocoapods

Hello I'm working on an old Objective-C project, that has 30+ pods dependecies, all written in Objective-C.

I'm trying to add a Swift pod, this one in particular :

```
pod 'CSV.swift', '~> 2.4.3'
# ...
# other Objective-C pods ...
# ...
```

Because I would like to continue new developments in Swift.

But I cannot make it work. If I add `use_frameworks!`, I get an error at pod install :

```
The 'Pods-myProject' target has transitive dependencies that include static binaries: (/myProjectPath/Pods/ObjcPod/ObjcPod.framework)
```

And if I remove `use_frameworks!`, I get tons of compilation errors, here are some :

```
Undefined symbol: protocol descriptor for Swift.UnicodeCodec
Undefined symbol: dispatch thunk of Swift.UnicodeCodec.decode<A where A1: Swift.IteratorProtocol, A.CodeUnit == A1.Element>(inout A1) -> Swift.UnicodeDecodingResult
```

I don't know what I could try otherwise, any help would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

This way you can use swift pod in objective c project try this solution.

Write in your pod file

```
target 'YourProjectName' do
use_frameworks!

pod 'CSV.swift', '~> 2.4.3'
// Here you can add mode pod as per your requirement Like
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'

end
```

Then Run Pod Install.

For import write this

```
@import CSV;
```

And then you have access of your CSV pod files.

Comment: If I add use_frameworks! I have an error at pod install as described in the question

Comment: I have tried in my code and its work, May be project have some other issue.